# Disable Evil-mode's state indication on mode line

Tags: evil, mode-line, mode-line-format

How do I disable evil-mode's state indicator on the mode line? I don't want to see anything like `<N>`, `<I>`, `<V>` on my modeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize `evil-mode-line-format` to `nil` for that.  Make sure to set it before Evil is enabled, as it only prevents the state indicator from being added to the mode line.